# Getting list of all tables in the database and the column information

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get all the information the current configured database in ZF2. Basically I can do it with queries. Eg.:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<databasename>'
```

.. and so on.

What i want, is to use something like PDO to provide me this info ( something like `$db->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` ). This is because i want it to work with different type of databases ( mysql, sqlite, etc... ).

Is there any way i could do this using zend's dbAdapter, or anything accessible from zend 2 framework ? Currently i was researching how to get a PDO instance and do it using it, but that won't happen from what i`ve seen included in ZF2 package.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `Zend\Db\Metadata` ? -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.1.4/modules/zend.db.metadata.html

Comment: thank you that will work great for me.